# C++ Program to calculate the number of white space in a text

Tags: c++

Why This program not working properly?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char x;
    int counter;
    while (x != '.') {
        cin >> x;
        if (x == ' ') {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    cout << counter;
}
```

i also tried to put the ascci code of the space character instead of ' '
but with no result.

Comment: In C++, if you don't initialize variables, they start with any somewhat random value.

Comment: You did not initialize `counter` or `x`. Both need to be initialized otherwise your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jeffrey Just to clarify, it doesn't actually start with a random value; it's much worse than that. The entire program is broken if that value is read, and anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

As other pointed out, you did not initialize x and counter variable. I don't know what is actual instruction of this exercise, but I wrote a simple program for counting the number of spaces in entered string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    std::string text;
    std::getline(std::cin, text);
    for (const auto &c : text) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << "Number of white spaces: " << counter << std::endl;
}
```

So let's get step by step. First we need to have a counter, to count number of white spaces, and we need to initialize it to 0. We also need to have some string, that we will count. In our case, this is text. So user will write something, and we will save that in variable text. After that, we will use loop, that was introduced in C++11, to iterate through every character and check if character is space. If character is space, then we will increment our counter. And the end of for loop, we can print the number of white spaces. Seems simple enough, doesn't it?